# Using partial? mysql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am having trouble in creating a query on a search field. There are two tables I have in my database and when I perform my search functionality I need only the `gsNumber` as a requirement on the search field.

I got stuck on the query since I need to use partial, and I have a problem on what's needed to select on both tables. I don't get on what's the use of partial.

Here is my code below:

```
public function getDetails($gsNumber,$page = 1, $limit = 5 ){
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT partial a.{ediTransactionId,gsNumber},
        partial b.{} 
        FROM MatrixEdiBundle:Edi997Details b
        JOIN a.ediTransaction b 
        WHERE a.errorCodeId != 1 AND a.gsNumber LIKE :gsNumber
        AND b.flag = 1')

        ->setParameter('gsNumber', "%$gsNumber%")

        ->setFirstResult(($page-1)*$limit)

        ->setMaxResults($limit);


    $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = false );
    $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);
    return $paginator;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you need b  in your result, so why not simply remove the 'partial b.{}' part?